# R--aggregate like function that ensures interactions of all factor levels

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I'm wondering how I can ensure I included all interactions of factors when using aggregate even if they don't appear in the given dataset.

```
dff <- data.frame(a=as.factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,4), rep(3,3))),
                  b=as.factor(c(rep("A", 4), rep("B",6))),
                  c=sample(100,10))

levels(dff$b) <- c(levels(dff$b), "C")
levels(dff$a) <- c(levels(dff$a), 10)

dff$b
#[1] A A A A B B B B B B
#Levels: A B C
dff$a
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
#Levels: 1 2 3 10

aggregate(c~a+b, dff, sum)
#  a b   c
#1 1 A 233
#2 2 A  78
#3 2 B 212
#4 3 B  73
```

what I want is

```
      a b   c
    1 1 A 233
    2 1 B   0
    3 1 C   0
    4 2 A  78
    5 2 B 212
    6 2 C   0
    7 3 A   0
    8 3 B  73
    9 3 C   0
   10 10 A  0
   11 10 B  0
   12 10 C  0
```

NA is fine too.

The reason I want it in this format is because I need to interact dff$c with results from other datasets and they may be of different length if not all factor levels are accounted for. I'm trying avoid merge and instead use vector calculation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `complete` from "tidyr" or `expand.grid` + `merge` in base R? Are you looking to solve *this* specific problem or just asking generally?

Comment: I ask because for this particular problem, you could just use `as.data.frame(xtabs(...))`, as in `as.data.frame(xtabs(c ~ a + b, dff))`.

Comment: When creating an example with a random process, add `?set.seed` for reproducibility.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to avoid `merge`?

Comment: Also `tapply` in `base` R keeps all the levels and you can get a `data.frame` through `as.data.frame.table`. In your case: `as.data.frame.table(tapply(dff$c,dff[,c("a","b")],sum))`.

Comment: both data.frame(xtabs) and tapply work great for my purpose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @A Handcart And Mohair: in my code, vector calculation would be a lot simpler than merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aggregation function is just going to be `sum`, you can just use `xtabs`, which would create an object that includes the class `table`. As such, you can use `data.frame`, which would call the respective "method", which creates a "long" `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(xtabs(c ~ b + a, dff))
#    b  a Freq
# 1  A  1  121
# 2  B  1    0
# 3  C  1    0
# 4  A  2   89
# 5  B  2  203
# 6  C  2    0
# 7  A  3    0
# 8  B  3  126
# 9  C  3    0
# 10 A 10    0
# 11 B 10    0
# 12 C 10    0
```

This is similar to @nicola's suggestion to use `as.data.frame.table`, which explicitly calls the method for something that is not explicitly of the class "table" but can be treated as one.

One advantage of this approach (and all the others that follow) is that you can use different functions other than `sum`.

```
as.data.frame.table(tapply(dff$c, dff[c("a","b")], sum))
```

If `merge` is OK, you can continue with your `aggregate` step. In this case, we use `expand.grid` on the `levels` of your factor vectors:

```
merge(expand.grid(lapply(dff[c(1, 2)], levels)), 
      aggregate(c~a+b, dff, sum, drop = FALSE), all = TRUE)
```

A similar approach can be taken in "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dff)[, sum(c), by = .(a, b)][do.call(CJ, lapply(dff[c(1, 2)], levels)), on = c("a", "b")]
```

Or using "dplyr" + "tidyr" (which essentially hides the merge, but ultimately uses `left_join` to create the missing combinations):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dff %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  summarise(c = sum(c)) %>%
  complete(a, b, fill = list(c = 0))
```

Comment: thank you for your help in the comment above and detailed explanation here!